# What is the difference when you execute cmake in a CMakeLists.txt versus you execute cmake in a terminal, and how can we make it behave the same?

Tags: c++, cmake

OK, I'm not sure how I can explain the problem exactly, but basically, in my *Project X*'s CMakeLists.txt, I'm building external library dependencies which are separate projects in itself (say, *Project A, Project B, Project C, Project D*) - then I build using `catkin_make`.

I use CMake's `ExternalProject_Add()` for each projects *A, B, C, D*; followed by a declaration of `add_dependencies()` to make projects *A, B, C, D* build first before the main *Project X*.

Now, I particularly have problems with *Project D*, having the need to set multiple paths to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` (eg, `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/addrA;/addrB;addrC`).

- **Error #1**: If I use `ExternalProject_Add()`, it recognizes the semicolon path separator ';' as *"end of the command"*, and thus, it cuts the cmake command through the first path (only `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/addrA` is recognized). I tried a lot of stuff already - usage of `LIST_SEPARATOR`, setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` before that using `set()`, or even using `$<SEMICOLON>` - nothing worked, same problem.
- **Error #2**: What I did next - is instead of using `ExternalProject_Add()` to do both download and build of *Project D* - I used `ExternalProject_Add()` to just do download (eg, BUILD_COMMAND will be just set to ""), and then do the build separately via `add_custom_target()`. Now the cmake command from there also didn't work - because for some reason/limitation I don't know about, it didn't properly map the `CMAKE_INSTALL_*` flags, and even though the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` was correct, it didn't really recognize the bin/lib/include directories that should've been automatically recognized inside the paths inside `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. When I try to replace the correct values of these flags in the resulting `CMakeCache.txt` and rebuild via `catkin_make`, it works fine. But if I don't do that, like if I rely only on the initial `CMakeCache.txt` it generated, it won't work.

***Please do take note, that when I try to run cmake of Project D in the terminal, I don't encounter any issues at all.***

As a workaround, I did an `execute_process()` that creates a bash script containing the cmake and make command for *Project D*, and then I just call that bash script  either at the `ExternalProject_Add()`'s `BUILD_COMMAND` or the `add_custom_target()`'s `COMMAND`. ***Either of these works - which just shows, that the cmake executed within a `COMMAND` of either `ExternalProject_Add()` or `add_custom_target()` is somehow different than executing cmake in a terminal or through a bash script.***

I've searched around everything here but I couldn't find anyone having the same problem as me, thus my workaround for now.

Here is the rough code that works (the one with my workaround):

```
### Project A 
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(ProjectA
    PREFIX             /tmp/ProjectA
    GIT_REPOSITORY     https://github.com/ProjectA
    GIT_TAG            v0.0.1
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND  ""
    BUILD_COMMAND      cmake -DWITH_GFLAGS=off -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ProjectA <SOURCE_DIR>
    COMMAND            sudo cmake --build . --target install
    INSTALL_COMMAND    ""
    TEST_COMMAND       ""
)

### Project B
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(ProjectB
    PREFIX             /tmp/ProjectB
    GIT_REPOSITORY     https://github.com/ProjectB
    GIT_TAG            v0.0.1
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND  ""
    BUILD_COMMAND      cmake -DLWS_STATIC_PIC=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ProjectB <SOURCE_DIR>
    COMMAND            sudo cmake --build . --target install
    INSTALL_COMMAND    ""
    TEST_COMMAND       ""
)

### Project C
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(ProjectC
    PREFIX             /tmp/ProjectC
    GIT_REPOSITORY     https://github.com/ProjectC
    GIT_TAG            v0.0.1
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND  ""
    BUILD_COMMAND      cmake -Dprotobuf_BUILD_TESTS=OFF -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ProjectC <SOURCE_DIR>
    COMMAND            sudo cmake --build . --target install
    INSTALL_COMMAND    ""
    TEST_COMMAND       ""
)

### Project D
execute_process (
    COMMAND bash -c "echo '#!/bin/bash\ncmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=\"/opt/ProjectA;/opt/ProjectB;/opt/ProjectC\" /tmp/ProjectD/src/ProjectD\nmake' > /tmp/projectD_build.sh"
    COMMAND bash -c "chmod 777 /tmp/projectD_build.sh"
)
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(ProjectD
    PREFIX             /tmp/ProjectD
    GIT_REPOSITORY     https://github.com/ProjectD
    GIT_TAG            master
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND  ""
    BUILD_COMMAND      /tmp/projectD_build.sh
    INSTALL_COMMAND    ""
    TEST_COMMAND       ""
)

### Set dependencies to force build Project A, B, C, D before Project X is build
add_library (ProjectX SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties (ProjectX PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${ProjectX_LIBS})
add_dependencies(ProjectX ProjectA)
add_dependencies(ProjectX ProjectB)
add_dependencies(ProjectX ProjectC)
add_dependencies(ProjectX ProjectD)

### Project X build commands here (snipped)
```

These are the cmake + make commands inside /tmp/ProjecD_build.txt:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/opt/ProjectA;/opt/ProjectB;/opt/ProjectC" /tmp/ProjectD/src/ProjectD
make
```

And if I replace the whole "### Project D" section with this, I encounter the **Error #1** that error I've discussed above (problem with multiple path CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH):

```
### Project D
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(ProjectD
    PREFIX             /tmp/ProjectD
    GIT_REPOSITORY     https://github.com/ProjectD
    GIT_TAG            master
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND  ""
    BUILD_COMMAND      cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/opt/ProjectA;/opt/ProjectB;/opt/ProjectC" /tmp/ProjectD/src/ProjectD
    INSTALL_COMMAND    make
    TEST_COMMAND       ""
)
```

... or add a post-ProjectD like this, it still doesn't work and causes **Error #2** I discussed above (CMAKE flags not properly set as seen in CMakeCache.txt). Note that with this solution, I the *Project D*  `ExternalProject_Add()`'s `BUILD_COMMAND` will be just set to "" since the build will be done by the added `add_custom_target()` instead:

```
ExternalProject_Get_Property(ProjectD install_dir)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(ProjectD source_dir)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(ProjectD binary_dir)
message(STATUS "install_dir is: " ${install_dir})
message(STATUS "source_dir is: " ${source_dir})
message(STATUS "binary_dir is: " ${binary_dir})

add_custom_target(ProjectD_part2 ALL
    cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/opt/ProjectA;/opt/ProjectB;/opt/ProjectC" ${source_dir}
    COMMAND make
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${binary_dir}
)

add_dependencies(ProjectD_part2 ProjectA)
add_dependencies(ProjectD_part2 ProjectB)
add_dependencies(ProjectD_part2 ProjectC)
add_dependencies(ProjectD_part2 ProjectD)
```

***The workaround works. But is there a better way of doing this? Thank you.***

Comment: Are you intentionally avoiding the use of the default configure/build commands (possibly with cmake args/cache args set)? I'm also under the impression that your `BUILD_COMMAND` should be the `CONFIGURE_COMMAND`, likewise install looks like it should be build.

Comment: @Hasturkun:

"Are you intentionally avoiding the use of the default configure/build commands (possibly with cmake args/cache args set)?"

Yes, I can't make do with the default configure/build commands. These customized build commands with args/prefix set are the requirements of the external Projects A, B, C and D.

"I'm also under the impression that your BUILD_COMMAND should be the CONFIGURE_COMMAND, likewise install looks like it should be build."

You are right. I actually swapped this in my local during my clean-up, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: OK. I didn't know if you were aware of the `CMAKE_ARGS`, `CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS`, etc parameters, and if they wouldn't apply from some reason. It looks like you might be able to set `LIST_SEPARATOR "|"`, use `|` instead of `;` and have it converted to `;`, though I haven't tried it (and it's exactly the opposite from what the documentation says it does).

Answer (score 0):

Looks complicated! Can you please try https://github.com/floooh/fips  which make lots of the cmake things easier.
Fips is a Python command line tool which provides an ‘Integrated Build Environment’ for C/C++ projects by wiring together existing build tools. It enables a workflow similar to Rust’s Cargo or Javascript’s NPM, but for C/C++ projects.

Comment: It is complicated indeed - and the limited documentations/sample codes of CMake for ExternalProject_Add() and add_custom_target() doesn't help...

Thank you - unfortunately, I can't use this fips, because I'm not allowed to use other third party sources for this (I have to resolve it within cmake directly - i.e., the solution must be a modification within the CMakeLists.txt itself).

Comment: On Stack Overflow we prefer the answers which provide information by themselves, not only via following the links. Could you update your answer with some additional information about what is behind the link you give? That way your answer will be really useful even without following the link. See also [answer].